# Function returning Int instead of float

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, function-pointers

I am experimenting with function pointers and lambdas in C++ and my function definitions are as follows -

```
float max(float a, float b){
    std::cout<<"In float max"<<std::endl;
    return (a > b) ? a : b;
}

int max(int a, int b){
    std::cout<<"In Int max"<<std::endl;
    return (a > b) ? a : b;
}

template<typename type1, typename type2>
int compareNumber(type1 a, type1 b, type2 function){
    return function(a, b);
}
```

and from my main function, I am calling it as follows -

```
int main(){

    std::cout<<compareNumber<float, float (float, float )>(5.2542f, 2.314f, max)<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<compareNumber<float>(1.3467f, 2.6721f, [=](float a, float b){
        return (a > b) ? a:b;
    })<<std::endl;

    std::cout<<max(5.3f, 2.7f)<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<max(1, 2)<<std::endl;
}
```

The Issue is that, If I simply invoke the function separately, the correct values get returned, but when using a lambda function or a function pointer, the values get cast to int for reasons I am not able to point out.
Here Is my output -

```
In float max
5
2
In float max
5.3
In Int max
2
```

I checked the output type of the output and it indeed is an integer. I had checked it as follows -

```
std::cout<<std::is_same<int, decltype(compareNumber<float, float (float, float )>(5.2542f, 2.314f, max))>()<<std::endl;
```

The above code snippet prints 1.
Could anyone please tell me as to what exactly is happening here?.
TIA

**PS - I just realized that the return type is `int` and not `type1` and had posted the question without thinking much and in a hurry. Sorry for the trivial question**

Comment: Look at the return type of `compareNumber`.

Comment: Oh god, this is embarrassing, that completely missed my eye. Thanks a lot for pointing it @interjay

Comment: You probably want to return `auto` type from compareNumber so it is the proper type regardless of the input types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
template<typename type1, typename type2>
int compareNumber(type1 a, type1 b, type2 function){
return function(a, b);
}
```

There is you code, you have change "int compareNumber" to "type1 compareNumber" because you don't know what type of variable you will get

```
template<typename type1, typename type2>
type1 compareNumber(type1 a, type1 b, type2 function){
return function(a, b);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I just noticed, the return type of the `compare` function is `int` and not `type1`. This had completely missed my eye. Sorry for the trivial question.